# Why does this selection sorting algorithmn still switch an element when it is already the smallest element among the rest?

Tags: c++, sorting

I was trying implementing a function that sort the elements of a int vector so that the elements goes from the smallest int to largest int (e.g. from {3, 2, 1, 5} to {1, 2, 3, 5}) but I somehow can not get it working as intended.

This is the function I created:

```
void increasingOrder(vector<int> &v)
{
    vector<int>::iterator itMin = v.begin();
    for (vector<int>::iterator itNew = v.begin(); itNew < v.end(); itNew++)
    {
        for (vector<int>::iterator it = itNew; it < v.end(); it++)
        {
            if (*it < *itMin)
                itMin = it;
        }
        int temp = *itNew;
        *itNew = *itMin;
        *itMin = temp;
    }
}
```

The intended algorithm of the function is basically this (selection sort):

1. Check all the elements
2. Pick the smallest
3. Switch it with the 1st element
4. Check the rest
5. Pick the smallest
6. Switch it with the 2nd element
7. Repeat until every element is switched.

The problem seems to happen when there is no need to switch an element, for example when arguement v = {3, 1, 2, 4}, the result would be {1, 2, 4, 3}, which to me seems like it still switched elements when there is no need to do so, but I am unsure about which piece of code resulted in such error, could anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean to know if a switch is done fix your problem :

```
void increasingOrder(vector<int> &v)
{
    vector<int>::iterator itMin = v.begin();
    for (vector<int>::iterator itNew = v.begin(); itNew < v.end(); itNew++)
    {
        bool isSwitched = false;
        for (vector<int>::iterator it = itNew; it < v.end(); it++)
        {
            if (*it < *itMin)
            {
                itMin = it;
                isSwitched = true;
            }
        }
        if (isSwitched)
        {
            int temp = *itNew;
            *itNew = *itMin;
            *itMin = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 2, 4 };
    increasingOrder(v);
}
```

Without that, even if a new itMin value isn't changed, you still switched it.